# puppeteer waitForSelector when there are multiple elements with same class and more than one can be visible

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

What i'm trying to accomplish is to save complete document with all the comments expanded.
Unfortunately there are multiple selectors with same class and most of them are hidden and what i believe puppeteer does it takes first found selector and waits until it's visible which never happens.

Url: https://www.discoverpermaculture.com/permaculture-masterclass-video-1

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const isElementVisible = async (page, cssSelector) => {
let visible = true;
await page
    .waitForSelector(cssSelector, { visible: true, timeout: 2000 })
    .catch(() => {
         visible = false;
     });
if(visible)console.log('Selector '+cssSelector+'visible!');
return visible;
};

async function run () {
let browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true, defaultViewport: null, args: ['--window-size=1920,10000',],});
const page = await browser.newPage();
const fs = require('fs');
await page.goto('https://www.discoverpermaculture.com/permaculture-masterclass-video-1');
await page.waitForTimeout(4000)

const elementHandle = await page.waitForSelector('iframe');
const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();
//loading all the comments (works because there's only one 'a.load-more__button' element a time)
const selectorForLoadMoreButton = 'a.load-more__button';
let loadMoreVisible = await isElementVisible(frame, selectorForLoadMoreButton);
while (loadMoreVisible) {
    console.log('Loading comments');
    await frame
        .click(selectorForLoadMoreButton)
        .catch(() => {});
    loadMoreVisible = await isElementVisible(frame, selectorForLoadMoreButton);
}
//expanding comments doesn't work because each comment have a.see-more but some are hidden
const selectorForSeeMoreButton = 'a.see-more';
let seeMoreVisible = await isElementVisible(frame, selectorForSeeMoreButton);
while (seeMoreVisible) {
    console.log('Expanding comments');
    await frame
        .click(selectorForSeeMoreButton)
        .catch(() => {});
    seeMoreVisible = await isElementVisible(frame, selectorForSeeMoreButton);
}
const cdp = await page.target().createCDPSession();
const { data } = await cdp.send('Page.captureSnapshot', { format: 'mhtml' });
fs.writeFileSync('out.mhtml', data);
browser.close();
}
run();
```

Any ideas how to handle this?

Comment: [URL](https://www.discoverpermaculture.com/permaculture-masterclass-video-1) currently shows error in console: `ReferenceError: PAGE_IDENTIFIER is not defined`

Comment: only error i was getting was "(node:12283) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: output is not defined" which is now fixed (edited original code)

Comment: What do you mean by "complete document with all the comments expanded". Do you want to export every comments to an xls file?

Comment: No. Save as mhtml will all the comments visible. For long comments disqus adds a clickable "See more" element. What i want to achieve is loop through all of them to make them fully visible and then save the page. I figured it out. Had to select all 'a.see-more' elements which doesn't have 'hidden' class. like this: 'a.see-more:not(.hidden)'.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that each comment have 'a.see-more' element but if it's not a long one it also have '.hidden' class. Had to update this piece of code to search for all the 'a.see-more' elements but without '.hidden' class.

```
    const selectorForSeeMoreButton = 'a.see-more:not(.hidden)';
    let seeMoreVisible = await isElementVisible(frame, selectorForSeeMoreButton);
    while (seeMoreVisible) {
        console.log('Expanding comments');
        await frame
            .click(selectorForSeeMoreButton)
            .catch(() => {});
        seeMoreVisible = await isElementVisible(frame, electorForSeeMoreButton);
    }
```